# KeyEvents for jnativehook

Tags: java, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, jnativehook

I'm trying to use [`jnativehook`](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) for global keyboard listeners but it seems like the key codes are different. For example, I want to check if <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> is pressed:

```
addNativeKeyListener(new NativeKeyAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent keyEvent)
    {
        val modifiers = keyEvent.getModifiers();
        val altPressed = modifiers == ALT_L_MASK;
        LOGGER.log(INFO, "Modifiers: " + modifiers + " ALT: " + ALT_L_MASK);

        if (!altPressed)
        {
            return;
        }

        val keyCode = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
        LOGGER.log(INFO, "Key code: " + keyCode + " VK_I: " + VK_I);
        if (keyCode != VK_I)
        {
            return;
        }

        LOGGER.log(INFO, "Button combination recognized...");
    }
});
```

Checking for the <kbd>ALT</kbd> modifier to be pressed works as expected but checking for the <kbd>I</kbd> button does not work as expected:

```
INFO: Modifiers: 8 ALT: 8
Oct 06, 2018 2:38:44 PM com.myCompany.Main nativeKeyReleased
INFO: Key code: 23 VK_I: 73
```

Why is the key code `23` when I release the <kbd>I</kbd> button? How do I check for the <kbd>I</kbd> button without hard-coding those seemingly random integer constants? Java offers the [`KeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) class for key codes but they're not applicable here, are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText()`](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/e8337e2a9bf3faf5180215aafc0049510ba8e01b/src/java/org/jnativehook/keyboard/NativeKeyEvent.java#L433) and then comparing to the String button does the trick but buttons then have to be stored as Strings which is okay:

```
public boolean isPressed(NativeKeyEvent keyEvent)
{
    val modifiers = keyEvent.getModifiers();
    val isModifierPressed = modifiers == modifier;

    if (!isModifierPressed)
    {
        return false;
    }

    val keyCode = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
    val keyText = NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode);
    return keyText.equals(this.keyText);
}
```

Note: [`val` is from `Lombok`](https://projectlombok.org/features/val).

Comment: Can you give an example of a more specific code? please

Comment: @VũĐạt: Yes, I added the `isPressed()` method I use

Comment: HI You can review image code https://imgur.com/a/LXD0VRK .I want to know where the modifier comes from

Comment: The `modifier` is `NativeInputEvent.ALT_L_MASK`